# Why doesn't the RegExp "greedy" mode work?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy, quantifiers

I do not understand the behavior. I have such example, need to catch html comment.

```
var str = '.. <!--My -- comment test--> ';

var regex1 = /<!--[.]*-->/g;
var regex2 = /<!--.*-->/g;

alert(str.match(regex1));      // null
alert(str.match(regex2));      // <!--My -- comment test-->
```

The second regex `regex2` works fine, outputs exactly what's needed. The first shows `null`. And I don't understand the difference. RegExpressions `<!--[.]*-->` and `<!--.*-->` mean the same - "after `<!--` take ANY character except newline in quantity from 0 to as many as possible and finish with `-->`". But for the second it works and for the first does not. Why?

UPD.
I've read comments and have an update.

```
var str3 = '.. <!--Mycommenttest--> ';
var str4 = '.. <!--My comment test--> ';

var regex3 = /<!--[\w]*-->/g;
var regex4 = /<!--[\s\S]*-->/g;

alert(str.match(regex3));         // <!--Mycommentstest-->
alert(str.match(regex4));         // <!-- My comment test -->
```

So it's possible to use limited matching variables to match anything. So which way should be used to use RegExps right way? With `[]` or without them? Can't get the difference, both give the right output.

Comment: Just so you know, "greedy" matching means that your pattern will match `<!-- Comment --> (Content) <!-- Another Comment -->`.  I suspect that is not what you want.

Comment: Note that `<!-- foo -- bar -->` is [an invalid HTML/SGML comment](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character class shorthands like `\w`, `\d` and `\s` mean exactly the same inside character classes as out, but metacharacters like `.` typically lose their special meanings inside character classes.  That's why `/<!--[.]*-->/` didn't work as you expected: `[.]` matches a literal `.`.

But `/<!--.*-->/` doesn't really work either, since `.` doesn't match newlines.  In most regex flavors you would use single-line mode to let the dot match all characters *including* newlines, like this: `/<!--.*-->/s` or this: `(?s)<!--.*-->`.  But JavaScript doesn't support that feature, so most people use `[\s\S]` instead, meaning "any whitespace character or any character that's *not* whitespace"--in other words, any character.

But that's not right either, since (as Jason pointed out in his comment) it will greedily match everything from the first `<!--` to the last `-->`, which could encompass several individual comments and all the non-comment material between them.  To make it truly correct is probably not worth the effort.  When using regexes to match HTML, you have to make many simplifying assumptions anyway; if you can't assume a certain level of well-formedness, you might as well give up.  In this case, it should suffice to make the quantifier non-greedy:

```
var regex5 = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g;
```

Answer (score 5):

The dot (`.`) does not mean "anything" inside a character class. Why would you need a character class to match anything?

Comment: Because you're using JavaScript?  ;)  With no single-line (or "DOTALL") mode, `.` never really matches *anything*, so you have to use a workaround like `[\s\S]`.

Comment: @AlanMoore Interesting note. I must admit that this was a quick and dirty answer that got too many upvotes, I didn't take the time to specify what _anything_ really means — apart from quoting it (a little subjective, but trying to say _anything but newlines_. This JavaScript peculiarity is something new for me. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of life's great mysteries.  Given JS's bizarre development model, I can understand it not supporting advanced features like lookbehinds and conditionals, but *single-line mode*?  That's like designing a car that can go straight or turn left, but can't turn right.

Answer (score 3):

> RegExpressions `<!--[.]*-->` and `<!--.*-->` mean the same

This is not correct.

The brackets `[]` indicate a character class, where any character in the class may be matched. `[.]` is the character class which contains the '`.`' character. Contrast this with `.`, which is a **pre-defined** character class taken to mean "any character" (except for line-terminators).

So what you're matching with `<!--[.]*-->` is either an empty comment or a comment consisting wholly of '`.`' characters. And what you're matching with `<!--.*-->` is either an empty comment or a comment filled with any character except linebreaks.

Answer (score 2):

The first doesn't because it doesn't mean the same.  The first means to match the period character.  The period character isn't a generic match when put inside of a [] set.  (and if you think about it, this makes sense: why would you want to match anything inside a set of limited matching variables)